# How can I set sendGrid to use sandbox with phpMailer

Tags: phpmailer, sendgrid

I use phpMailer to send out emails and set the SMTP to use sendGrid.
I am trying to set the account to Sandbox mode to simulate a large list to ensure it won't time out.

Sendgrid docs show I can add a parameter to the mail_settings for sandbox_mode to be enabled. But I can't figure out how to send additional mail settings using phpMailer.
(For all other settings, there seems to be a preset parameter - ex `$mail->SMTPDebug = true`)

For reference, Sendgrid Docs are

https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/sandbox-mode
and

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/main/examples/helpers/mail/example.php